# Does Facebook API video-upload work only with OAuth v1?

Tags: api, facebook, video, oauth

I cannot get video upload to work with OAuth 2 access-token. The request always fails to even connect (timeout).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/video.upload

With almost identical code, I have successfully uploaded photos.

The only video-upload example code I can find uses OAuth 1.x. Does video not yet support OAuth 2?

Thanks to all who read this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is the case. New graph api still missing some of the functionality from old REST api. And that includes uploading video. You should be able to use REST api with access token to do things not yet supported by graph api.